# Rails API with a single access key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rails-api

*After searching S/O, I haven't found anything that directly answers my question, so I'll ask:*

I want to have a front-end web application (just Javascript) powered by a separate back-end Rails server. So, in order to get and store data, the web app sends requests to the Rails server. My question:

> How can I ensure that requests to the server are only given a
>   successful response if the request comes from the web application?
>   Then, how do I implement this with Rails? (The second part I can
>   probably figure out, the first question is the most important.)

**Edit:** I think this part may be unclear after reading responses -- I only have *one* client for the server. That is,

> I want the server to only accept responses from the front-end web app
>   and from no other sources (that is, someone should not be able to type
>   in a url in their browser and get a successful response from the
>   server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement some sort of authentication. Devise could help with this, storing authentication information in the users session. Then in your controllers you can use something like `before_filter :authenticate_user!`

If your server is available over the open internet, you either need named user authentication (useful for other things besides auth, like tracking users) or run it as a public api not caring if users hit it (but then you need rate limiting to avoid unintentional ddos, adding another layer of complexity).

Comment: There is no sort of user -- maybe I didn't communicate this properly, but there is only one client for the server. The client (the front-end web app) should be the only thing allowed to make requests to the server.

Comment: I would roll my own HTTP basic authentication and hard code the password/user in the client. In the client web app can multiple users log in?

Comment: There are no users at all. It just queries the server to get and send information (to be more specific, arrays which it stores and retrieves from the server). Also, I was thinking of doing what you are doing -- hard coding the client -- but the only problem is that people could just look at the requests being send, take those hard coded API keys, use them to make requests, and then the keys would be pointless.

Comment: Are the client and server both behind your firewall? we have some apps and internal api's that we leave open only because they can not be accessed over the internet. I think you are in between a rock and hard place, if your server is available over the open internet, you either need named user authentication (useful for other things besides auth, like tracking users) or run it as a public api not caring if users hit it (but then you need rate limiting to avoid unintentional ddos, adding another layer of complexity).

Comment: Ok got it. I'll just do that instead. Perhaps I was adding an extra layer of complexity because I was developing the back-end while my buddy was developing the front end. One last thing -- if you could, include your last comment as part of your answer, as that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

create some sort of authentication system.. so that ServerApp knows that request is coming from trusted source.

After storing data.. based on success or failure you can return back Json/Xml data with appropriate message.

not sure what else you are asking for, let me know if you need further assistance with this.

Comment: My question is more "How do I build this authentication system?" rather than "how does this process work". I want to know how to make sure that the server application only accepts responses from one source.